# Duplicates inserting from csv to salesforce through jitterbit data loader!

Tags: data-loader, jitterbit

I am using free Jitterbit to load files (.csv) from SFTP into Salesforce (custom object). In FTP, xls files are fed and is converted into .csv file (via php) and that csv file is inserted into Salesforce. During this process, duplicate records are being inserted. For example, if that xls file has got 100 records, then number of records being inserted into Salesforce are 200.

I did manual testing, wherein, I took the xls fiel and converted it into csv file and kept in FTP. Apparently, there are no duplicates found.

Would like to know what could be happening during this process.

Comment: Responding to a flag from the community. This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a very specific scenario, and the chances of someone searching the web, finding this question and then finding the answer helpful are slim to none!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the maximum number of threads to 1.

Document Link: http://www.jitterbit.com/Docs/WebHelp/Operations/Operation_Options.htm

Comment: Thanks Eric for the reply. I figured out the problem which was scheduling running  every 15 mins and because I have multiple triggers running and for which I set the chunk size as 1. Since the file size is large and chunk size is 1, loading is exceeding 15 minutes and when the job is running again, it is finding the same file in the FTP. Hence, duplicates are being inserted.